# How to end a tag in Razor without razor complaining no start tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I got this code:

```
@foreach (var team in Model.GetTeams)
{
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var employee in team.Medewerkers)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            @:<li class="flip-card">
                @:<div class="flip-card-back">
                @:</div>
                i=1;                                    
        } 
        else
        {
                @:<div class="flip-card-front">
                @:</div>
            @:</li>
            i = 0;
        } 
    }
    if (i == 1)
    {
        </li>
    }
}
```

Now it's possible that there are 3 employees in a team so the `li` tag would never close. So I thought I would add an if statement at the end to check if `i == 1` so I can close the `li` tag but when I use this code, Razor complains that I close a tag which is never started.

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Your code and question makes no sense to me. As a start though you have three opening brackets in the first section of code with only two closing...

Comment: Can you add the expected output of your code?

Comment: Please check my edited question. My expected output is <li></li> whether I got 3 employees or 4employees

Comment: Are you wanting a single `<li>` containing a `<div>` for each employee or one `<li>` for each employee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to close `<li class="flip-card">` after every two employees, or after the last employee when the number of employees is odd. For example you want this output when there are 2 employees

```
<li class="flip-card">
    <div class="flip-card-back">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-front">
    </div>
</li>
```

and you want this output when there are 3 employees

```
<li class="flip-card">
    <div class="flip-card-back">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-front">
    </div>
</li>
<li class="flip-card">
    <div class="flip-card-back">
    </div>
</li>
```

Instead of changing the value of `i` to `0` and `1`, I would suggest keep adding the value of `i` by 1 and use [% operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) to check whether the current value of `i` is odd or even. The closing `</li>` should only be added when `i` is odd or `i` equals `team.Medewerkers.Count - 1`. Change your code as below

```
@foreach (var team in Model.GetTeams)
{
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var employee in team.Medewerkers)
    {
        if (i == 0 || i % 2 == 0)
        {
            @:<li class="flip-card">
                @:<div class="flip-card-back">
                @:</div>
        } 
        else
        {
                @:<div class="flip-card-front">
                @:</div>
        }
        if (i % 2 == 1 || i == team.Medewerkers.Count - 1)
        {
            </li>
        }
        i++;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that I could do something like i % 2